# Pagination Laravel 6.x

Tags: laravel-6

Iam using customized pagination which is pagination bulma CSS on laravel pagination with laravel 6.x version

Why did I get this little black dot on my pagination??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to here : https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/bulma

You should replace your published bootstrap-4.blade.php file with this one : https://gist.github.com/Laraveldeep/362490aead2fc4b2fd15c3aae24254cf

Or, try adding this to your css file :

```
.pagination li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect on pagination li class and make them 
    list-style-type: none;